# Can I use any feature selection methods for clustering tasks like KMeans in Scikit-learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, feature-selection

I want to test some feature selection methods on not labeled data but fit() methods of objects in sklearn.feature_selection have mandatory y parameter (target vector). Are there any built in methods for feature selection that can be used for clustering tasks (where I don't have to specify target vector and can use only sample data)?

Comment: Perhaps you can perform PCA on your data.

Comment: I don't think there's much in the way of unsupervised feature selection available; although one that jumps out is `VarianceThreshold` http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.VarianceThreshold.html

Comment: Thanks, VarianceTreshold works fine.

Comment: @Ryan is there any other way in Pandas for this purpose? Like an algorithm or something?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SequentialFeatureSelector in sklearn.
https://scikit-learn.org/0.24/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SequentialFeatureSelector.html

Comment: I think OP is expecting a solution for feature selection in unsupervised setting, hence there would be no target variable to feed in.